# Web scraping with BeautifulSoup - unable to extract table rows

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the table on the following webpage using BeautifulSoup:

https://www.indiapost.gov.in/VAS/Pages/PMODashboard/DistributionOfPostOffices.aspx

The code I'm trying to use is:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.indiapost.gov.in/VAS/Pages/PMODashboard/DistributionOfPostOffices.aspx"
html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
type(soup)

table = soup.find('table', {'class' : 'tbl'})

#extract rows:

rows = soup.find_all('tr')
```

The last line of should print output along the row names with the HTML tags (ie Sl No., Head Post Office etc), but it merely prints an empty list. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: the table is rendered by javascript, you should consider using selenium to retrieve JS rendered page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna comply with the following approach to get the tabular content from that webpage using requests. Turn out that the content you look for are available in this ***[link](https://www.indiapost.gov.in/Documents/DashboardXmlFile/DashboardXML.xml)*** which you can locate using chrome dev tools.

Working code:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.indiapost.gov.in/Documents/DashboardXmlFile/DashboardXML.xml'

def get_tabular_info(link):
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'xml')
    tabular_list = []
    for items in soup.select("DistributionOfPostOffices Table1")[2:]:
        tabular_list.append([item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("A,B,C,D,E,F")])
    return tabular_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("output_indiapost.csv","w",newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        for item in get_tabular_info(url):
            writer.writerow(item)
            print(item)
```

Output are like:

```
['Sl. No.', 'Circle Name', 'Head Post Office', 'Sub Post Office', 'Branch Post Office', 'Letter Box']
['1', 'Andhra Pradesh Circle', '59', '1535', '8897', '29510']
['2', 'Assam Circle', '19', '606', '3385', '12427']
['3', 'Bihar Circle', '32', '1029', '8031', '22433']
['4', 'Chhattisgarh Circle', '11', '341', '3079', '14988']
['5', 'Delhi Circle', '12', '406', '142', '1187']
['6', 'Gujarat Circle', '33', '1243', '7651', '24377']
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The output though, is a NoneType object. Possible to convert it into a csv or render into pandas dataframe?

Comment: Check out the edit. Btw, what makes you think that `The output is a NoneType object`?

Comment: Thanks, passing get_tabular_info(url) to type returns NoneType.

Comment: The function was not returning anything and that is the reason you got that type. The above function returns the result now and then write them to a csv file. I'm still unclear why do you wanna go this route. Thanks.